# how to get list of previous n values of a column in a new column of current row?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

My pandas dataframe looks like below:

```
Index   Score
1       15.5
2       0.0
3       15.5
4       30.0
5       17.5
```

I want to get the previous 3 scores as a list in new column like below

```
Index   Score   Pre_Scr
1       15      []
2       0       [15]
3       18      [0,15]
4       30      [18,0,15]
5       17      [30,18,0]
5       5       [17,30,18]
```

I tried

```
[x.values.tolist() for x in v.rolling(3)]
```

But this returns a list including the current value. How do I get it in the above expected format against each record?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to remove the last value, why not do this to remove the current value:

```
[x.values.tolist()[:-1] for x in v.rolling(4)]
```

Comment: Simple. Thanks.

Comment: Any idea how to roll conditionally? For example in the above case roll it based on index column. Odd rows separately even rows separately?

Answer (score 1):

If I got your variables right, you can do it this way:

```
 [[y for y in x.values.tolist() if y != v_no] for x, v_no in zip(v.rolling(4), v.values) ]
```

or probably (once it is going to be implemented for non-time datatypes):

```
 [x.values.tolist() for xin v.rolling(4, closed='left')]
```

Comment: @scophros, i have updated my question. it is x in v, not xin. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: And I updated mine. However, it seems that @Shubham Lohiya got a simpler.

Comment: @scophros Thanks. Any idea how to roll conditionally? For example in the above case roll it based on index column. Odd rows separately even rows separately?

Comment: You can use indexing - use twice longer rolling window and then apply odd indexing: `list[::2]` or `list[1::2]`

Comment: Sorry. My question was not just about odd or even. In general how do i group records based on another column.

Comment: Why won't you read about [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)?